# Is the following statement about complex integration over the boundary of a closed rectangle correct?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, analysis

I have the following statement

> Let $f:\Omega\rightarrow \Bbb{C}$ be analytic. Take $R\subset \Omega$ a closed rectangle then $$\int_{\partial R} f(z)dz=0$$

Now I wanted to ask if this statement is true as it is written above because in my opinion one should also say that $\Omega$ is open or isn't this needed? Because in the prove we used the statement:

> Let $B\subset \Bbb{C}$ be an open ball, $f:B\rightarrow \Bbb{C}$ be analytic, then for alle closed curves $\gamma:[a,b]\rightarrow B$ $$\int_{\gamma}f(z)dz=0$$

But to apply the second statement don't we need some conditions on $\Omega$?

Thanks for your help

Comment: "O"mega is typically an "open" domain, notational convention.

Comment: @KevinS perfect thanks!

Comment: @geetha290krm sorry what? So we have seen this statement in class if it is wrong I have some huge problems. Is it really wrong?

Comment: @geetha290krm sure it should be $\gamma$ my mistake, but then it is correct?

Comment: Yes, it is now correct.

Comment: @geetha290krm perfect thanks!

Comment: IIRC, the customary definition of _analytic_ for a function $f$ of one complex variable guarantees the domain is open. The same is true of _holomorphic_ but for different reasons.